# cellForRowAt indexPath function not called - Swift tableView

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a tableView that is displayed in my Storyboard and in the Preview but when I run it on my device it does not display.  When debugging, I realize that the issue seems to be that it never runs the cellForRowAt indexPath function.  Why does this code not execute that function, I ould expect for it to output 2 rows.

EDIT: numberOfRowsInSection is being called and returns 2 for the data.count

Here is my ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class WRViewController: PopupViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var wrNo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

struct Contact {

    var name:String
    var type:String
    var phone:String

}
var data:[Contact]=[Contact]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    data.append(Contact(name:"John Doe",type:"Builder",phone:"1234567890"))
    data.append(Contact(name:"Jane Doe",type:"Contractor",phone:"0987654321"))

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.reloadData()

}

override func prepareToOpen() {
    super.prepareToOpen()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath)

    let contactView = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.text = contactView.name
    cell.image = contactView.type
    cell.text = contactView.phone

    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: Is `numberOfRowsInSection` being called? Does `data` have two elements when it is called? Does the table view have a valid frame?

Comment: "When debugging, I realize that the issue seems to be that it never runs the cellForRowAt indexPath function" No, it's likely the other way round. Your data source methods are not called if the table view does not need to display. Something is wrong with your configuration in the storyboard, perhaps? You aren't getting any warnings in the storyboard? Use the View Debugger to figure out where your table view went.

Comment: @matt That does make sense.  This is the first time I have used the view debugger so I am not entirely sure what I should be looking for.  The only warning I see is that the height of my stack view is ambiguous.  When I click on the TableView it does not highlight anything.

Comment: How is your autolayout situation for the cells? do you use automatic cell dimension ?

Comment: @Alan I have the cell height set to 100 and the content of the cell within 1 stack view that is combining 3 stack views (3 rows of Label/Value)

Comment: ok what you are saying is if you set a breakpoint in cellForRowAt it doesn't stop there right ?

Comment: @Alan That is correct.. the breakpoint does stop at numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: "the height of my stack view is ambiguous" Yup, that's exactly what I thought. That's the problem right there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you have not supplied sufficient autolayout constraints to determine the height of this table view. Therefore it has no height. Therefore it doesn't need to show any cells. Therefore it doesn't *ask* for any cells.

The storyboard and/or the view debugger has been warning you quite clearly that this is a problem, but you didn't pay any attention. Well, pay attention! Add a height constraint or top and bottom constraints, so that this table view has a height.

(Note that the problem might not be just with the table view, but with whatever it is vertically pinned to. But you have given no information about that, so it's impossible to say, from here.)

Comment: Thanks matt - I was setting constraints on the stack view that contained the tableView, but I actually needed to apply those constraints to the parent stack view as well.

Comment: This is definitely the best possible answer, if everything else is set up correctly, then the issue is in constraints; I've faced this many times when creating UITableView inside UITableViewCell.